# uck or other software for creating customized iso

Tags: uck

can someone tell whether uck on command line does not work with version 2.4.5 or 2.4.6. I wish to create a livecd using commands of uck not uck-gui but while running the command uck-remaster-pack-rootfs it gives an error as "failed to read" and problem with uck-gui is one has to finalise the work and create the iso. it does not allow to continue work later. everytime even if a small change is made one has to build an iso. For again making changes this new iso has to be used.

Is there any other better option available to create livecd wihout making use of uck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Remastersys](http://www.remastersys.klikit-linux.com/)s to create a custom ISO.  Remastersys is very handy application that allows you to clone and backup your Linux distribution, including root, home, other partitions, and all personal, custom configuration to a fully deploy-able, bootable live CD.

Also you may want to look at [Live CD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization), and [Install CD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization)

Answer (score 1):

The best current alternative is https://github.com/kamilion/customizer

Remastersys, Ubuntu Builder, Novo Builder, UCK and a few others have all stopped development.

This has been around before UCK and is still in development today!